# Expander header display Number of Items with specific property

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I have a listview which is Grouped by Properties of the underlying Datasource.
The Groupstyle contains a Expander with an Header in which I want to display various things.
The listview shows Emails which are for example grouped by subject.
I know want to display (UnreadMailCount/Items) in each Group Header.

My Solution so far is:

```
<ListView Name="Mails" local:FM.Register="{Binding}" local:FM.GetFocus="Loaded"
                  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MailsProxy.View}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMail, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    local:SortList.BringIntoViewSelected="True" local:SortList.IsGridSortable="True"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource InboxMailItem}"
                    View="{Binding Source={x:Static session:Session.Current}, Path=InboxView.View}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}" Expanded="OnExpand" Collapsed="OnCollapse" Loaded="OnLoad">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.GroupBy}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14">:</TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource GroupHeaderConverter}}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock> </TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Margin="0,1,0,0">(</TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.Unread}"/>
                                                    <!--<TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding StringFormat=0, Converter={StaticResource InboxGroupSeenConverter}}" />-->
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14">/</TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14">)</TextBlock>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static session:Session.Current}, Path=InboxView}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

As you can see i tried to display the unread Mailitems by using a converter ( -->) this works, except, that the Header is not updated after the Property of the Mailitem is changed.

The Converter:

```
public class InboxGroupSeenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GetTotalUnread(value as CollectionViewGroup);
    }

    private static int GetTotalUnread(CollectionViewGroup group)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (eMail mailItem in group.Items)
            if (mailItem.Seen == false)
                count++;
        return count;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with the Converter or should I go a different way by using Properteis as seen above ()

Edit: To clarify my Question. The Header of My group displays must display two different numbers. One being the ItemCount of the Group, the second being the number of Unread items within this group.
The number of unread Items is calculated within my converter which was a test for me, however this solution does not update the view if the underlying collection properties change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your `Expander` needs DynamicResource Style.
BTW Expander has it's own properties which you can use for your solution here is an example in the question I answered before

[WPF-ListView-GridView-allow users...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626926/wpf-listview-gridview-allow-users-to-select-multiple-items-and-group-them-togeth/21229558#21229558)

good luck and let us know :-)

**EDIT**

tomorrow I'll come back to you, as I am finishing work soon :-), remember that expander has it's own itemsCount so there is no need to implement your own, second thing is to implement in your email object property `bool Unread` than just bind it to your textblock style using DataTriggers and voila!

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? And tell me how you would style the header / bind the Text Property in this Style?

Comment: Well rather than using StaticResource in your style you could use something along these lines
`<Expander Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle}">`

Comment: The Style is not my problem. I want the Text Property of my TextBlock Element within the Expanders Dockpanel to have a proper Binding, which solves my problem of updates, which I get iif I use a Converter.

Comment: Might be my english or something else but you don't get my problem. I know that the expander has an own Property itemcount and I am already using it. Also my mailitem has a property read/unread which I am using in my converter. The problem is to get the number of all unread items in the group for every expander and display this number .
The expander works as grouping mechanism for mailitems. the mailitems may be grouped by subject. Therefore a group can contain 10 items (ItemCount) but only 5 of the are already marked as read (Mailitem.Read) Now I want to display 5/10 in this group header.

Comment: Hi pal, I think your english spot on, mea culpa :-)
Anyways getting back to the problem,
Have you tried setting the Binding to work both ways in your `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MailsProxy.View ,**Mode=TwoWay** }"` I would also check your list sorter maybe that's where notification doesn't occur?

Comment: BTW I will insist on you to change the Style Property of the expander as it will allow the expander to pick up the chnges as static resource is used on initialisation while DynamicResource is being evaluated at runtime. Give it a go and let us know :-)